# How can I setup my domain correctly on MailGun?

Tags: email, dns, parse-platform, mailgun

This might be my only problem.  I get this message under my domain names in my account on mailgun:

`Warning: Some of your domains (in red) have DNS configuration issues.`

What can I do about that?  I've tried a huge random domain name and it does the same thing.

Thank you for taking a look!

-------------------------- In case this is not my only problem --------------------------------

I am using parse.com with MailGun.  I have all my parse stuff setup and I've made an account with MailGun and added a custom domain name with MailGun.  Here is my iOS code:

```
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"This is sent from your iPhone." forKey:@"text"];
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"emailGrocery" withParameters:params block:^(id object, NSError *error)
    {
        if(!error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Succeeded");
        }
        else
        {
            NSString *errorMsg = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
            NSLog(@"%@", errorMsg);
        }
    }];
```

This is in an example from parse.  And I think this is doing what it should, as I get the error message in my log.

Here is my cloud code that is being hit:

```
 var Mailgun = require('mailgun');
 Mailgun.initialize('domain.com', 'key');

 Parse.Cloud.define("emailGrocery", function(request, response) {
 Mailgun.sendEmail({
   to: "myemail@gmail.com",
   from: "myemail@gmail.com",
   subject: "Hello from Cloud Code!",
   text: "Using Parse and Mailgun is great!"
 }, {
   success: function(httpResponse) {
     console.log(httpResponse);
     response.success("Email sent!");
   },
   error: function(httpResponse) {
     console.error(httpResponse);
     response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
   }
 });
});
```

I have my actual email address in there as the sender and another known email address as the receiver.  I always get the error response back.  I have an actual domain and key in there.  In my account on mailgun under my custom email domain names there is this message:

`Warning: Some of your domains (in red) have DNS configuration issues.`

I can't figure out what I should do about this.  I realize that that might be my only issue, but what do I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

I want to share 2 screenshots that might help verifying custom domain for Mailgun in Namecheap... I banged my head against the wall for 2 days :)

[image]

[image]

Mailgun has a button check your DNS settings and sometimes it gives false negatives so try it a few times

Comment: I want to highlight : mailo._domainkey.mg without domain.com

Answer (score 2):

You need to verify your domain with SPF and DKIM. You can do this by adding TXT DNS records.

See more info at
https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#verifying-your-domain

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this thread while troubleshooting my own and wanted to provide another host's configuration.  I have a website on a VPS and the domain registar is the host.  I am configuring the DNS in WHM.  Please see my examples below:

[This is the Mailgun page with the examples and check settings for the domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdqCk.png)

[This is the WHM DNS records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTUX5.png)